# What is Submatrix Sum Queries program?. What is its use and concept to build it

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I found this question in geeksforgeeks. It was asked in an amazon interview process. Following is the link:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/submatrix-sum-queries/

If anyone has any idea of is this ques, please explain to me.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation on how to solve it is in great detail behind the link you provided.

Comment: This link doesn't explain what is its use and what its concept.

Comment: Are you more generally asking about the reason and use of preprocessing data or something specific about this example?

Comment: I am asking about this matrix problem only. Why is this resultant matrix used. Wat is its pratical use and what is the rule to create submatrix sum

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sumMatSumInConstantTime(int[][] mat, int is, int js, int ie, int je) {

    processMatForConstantTimeSum(mat);

    int sum = mat[ie][je];
    int count = 0;
    if (is - 1 >= 0) {
        sum -= mat[is - 1][je];
        count++;
    }
    if (js - 1 >= 0) {
        sum -= mat[ie][js - 1];
        count++;
    }
    /**
     * since one rectangle is deducted twice
     */
    if (count == 2)
        sum += mat[is - 1][js - 1];

    return sum;
}

private static void processMatForConstantTimeSum(int[][] mat) {

    int r = mat.length;
    int c = mat[0].length;

    /**
     * sum rows
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            sum += mat[i][j];
            mat[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    /**
     * sum cols
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            sum += mat[j][i];
            mat[j][i] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```